# Python: Informing user of divide by zero error

Tags: python, function, zero, divide, divide-by-zero

I'm writing a program with a number of simple operating functions. Keep in mind I'm fairly new to this. As you can see, if a user types "0" as one of the values, the obvious "Cannot divide by zero" error appears. I would like some advice on how to make a special case that prints "Cannot divide by zero.") as opposed to showing an error message.

```
def AddTwoNumbers(num1,num2):
    totalAdded= num1 + num2
    return totalAdded

def SubTwoNumbers(num1,num2):
    totalSubtract= num1 - num2
    return totalSubtract

def MultiTwoNumbers(num1,num2):
    totalMultiply= num1 * num2
    return totalMultiply

def DivideTwoNumbers(num1,num2):
    totalDivide= num1 / num2
    return totalDivide

firstNum=int(input("Enter first number:"))
secondNum=int(input("Enter second number:"))

addResult=AddTwoNumbers(firstNum, secondNum)
subResult=SubTwoNumbers(firstNum, secondNum)
multiResult=MultiTwoNumbers(firstNum, secondNum)
diviResult=DivideTwoNumbers(firstNum, secondNum)

print(firstNum, "+", secondNum, "=", addResult)
print(firstNum, "-", secondNum, "=", subResult)
print(firstNum, "x", secondNum, "=", multiResult)
print(firstNum, "/", secondNum, "=", diviResult)
```

Comment: make use of python [`try statements`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#try) (hint, add one of these inside of your `Divide Two Numbers` function)

Comment: You could use an [if statement](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html) to detect the 0 case.

Answer (score 2):

You should use a [try/except](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#try):

So, for your method here:

```
def DivideTwoNumbers(num1,num2):
    totalDivide= num1 / num2
    return totalDivide
```

Simply, use a try/except around your `totalDivide = num1 / num2` to catch the `ZeroDivisionError` and then perform whatever operation you want in there.

This is an example:

```
try:
    5/0
except ZeroDivisionError:
    print("You tried dividing by zero")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
try:
  result=DivideTwoNumbers(a,b)
except ZeroDivisionError as e:
  print str(e)
```

or

```
if num2 == 0: 
   print "you cant divide by zero dummy"
   return None
```

Comment: I tried this, however it causes a few errors further down the program. How would it look as a complete program?